# Is there a way to make the look up column dynamic in excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to do something like this:

```
For i = 1 To 10

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(THIS VALUE,'IN THIS TABLE RANGE,i,FALSE)"

Next i
```

I want to pass the value of i to the column value to be looked up.

Comment: FWIW, that's quite inefficient, as you are looking up the same value 10 times. Better to use MATCH in one column to get the right row and then use that directly in 10 INDEX formulas.

Comment: whats' your real goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use string manipulation as below:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(THIS VALUE,'IN THIS TABLE RANGE," & i & ",FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Only use `FormulaR1C1` if you use `R1C1` references, otherwise use `Formula`

This will put the formula in the 10 first on the 1st row, on the sheet named `SheetName` :

```
With Sheets("SheetName")
    For i = 1 To 10
        .Cells(1, i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(THIS VALUE,IN THIS TABLE RANGE," & i & ",FALSE)"
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

you could be after something like this

```
Cells(1, 1).Resize(, 10).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(""THIS_VALUE"",R2C1:R100C10,COLUMN(),FALSE)"
```

where you have to change:

- `Cells(1, 1)` to your actual cell reference you want to start writing formula down from
- `R2C1:R100C10` to actual "TABLE RANGE" address in `R1C1` style
- `COLUMN()` to proper difference between written cells column index and "TABLE RANGE" ones (e.g. it could be some `COLUMN()-1`)